Entity Framework - diagram remove field and mapping
I have a development and a production SQL database lets call them dbD and dbP for ease:

dbD has field1, field2, field3 (f2 & f3 are part of a future project and are only to be in dpD)

dbP has field1


When the code runs using dbP, it fails because it can't reference f2 or f3.
I have tried:

Removing the mappings to f2 and f3.
Removing f2 and f3 from the diagram model.

I have done clean builds with both of the above but every time I switch to the dpP server I get the error below.

Models.TestTable.msl(126,10):
Error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 126:
No mapping specified for properties TestTable.field1, TestTable.field2 in Set TestTables.
An entity with key (PK) will not round-trip when entity is type [TestTableDBModel.TestTable]

How can I deploy to a production server with different fields without entity complaining?

Problem appears to be related to cacheing, cleared all built files manually and rebuilt. All working fine now.
Got to love little quirks in VS..
